# How to combine two service into one

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two classes like following

```
@Service
class BookService {
    @Autowired 
    BookRepository repository;

    public Book findById(Long id){
        Book book =  repository.findById(id);
        if (book==null){
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity Not found with given id: "+id);
        }
        return book;
    }

    public Book save(Book book){
        return repository.save(book);
    }
}



@Service
class AuthorService {
    @Autowired
    AuthorRepository repository;

    public Author findById(Long id){
        Author author =  repository.findById(id);
        if (author==null){
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity Not found with given id: "+id);
        }
        return author;
    }

    public Author save(Author author){
        return repository.save(author);
    }
}
```

If you look closely, then you will see both looks almost same. Only difference they both deals with two separate object.

So is there anyway to write one class to deal with this kind of duplicate?

Comment: There a reason you're not using something like Spring's [data-rest project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest)?

Comment: There are others thing this service does. I am looking for a way to minimize common code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create generic `CrudService<T, ID>` and `CrudAbstractService<T, ID>` with default logic for storing/retrieving your objects like.

```java
public interface CrudService<T, ID> {
    T save(T entity);

    T find(ID id);
}
```

```java
public abstract class CrudAbstractService<T, ID> implements CrudService<T, ID> {

    private final JpaRepository<T, ID> repository;

    public CrudAbstractService(JpaRepository<T, ID> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public T find(ID id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Entity Not found with given id: " + id));
    }

}
```

And then just extend your BookService or any other service with this logic

```java
public interface BookService extends CrudService<Book, Long> {
    // service-specific methods for example findBooksByAuthor(String author);
}
```

```java
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl extends CrudAbstractService<Book, Long> implements BookService {

    private final BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public BookServiceImpl(BookRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // implement here service-specific logic from BookService interface

}
```

Then you could create `CrudController` for these operations and use it across your entities.

```java
public abstract class CrudController<T, ID> implements CrudService<T, ID> {

    private final CrudService<T, ID> service;

    public CrudController(CrudService<T, ID> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public T save(@RequestBody T entity) {
        return service.save(entity);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public T find(@PathVariable ID id) {
        return service.find(id);
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController extends CrudController<Book, Long> {

    private final BookService service;

    @Autowired
    public BookController(BookService service) {
        super(service);
        this.service = service;
    }
    // other BookService specific logic
}
```

Notice, this approach could increase the **complexity** of your code, but it **reduces duplication** and create a **reusable** mechanism for CRUD operations. You should choose between these parameters. If your application is **small** and **not extendable**, it better to use **simple duplication**.

Answer (score 2):

Use object programming logic:

```
   @Service
    class RepService {
        IRepository = repositoryClass;

        public T FindById<T>(Long id) where T : class {
            T findItem =  repository.findById(id);
            if (author==null){
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity Not found with given id: "+id);
            }
            return findItem;
        }

        public T Save<T>(T obj) where T : class {
             return repository.Save(obj);
        }
    }
```

Then you need BookRepository and AuthorRepository to implement an IRepository. Also they need to init their respective repositoryClass in constructor.

Comment: note you can (would be better) set the generic on the class declaration:
class RepService <T> where T : class, new() {

Comment: can you please edit your answer and put you note in comment in full form